# Dataproc Cluster with only preemptible workers

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm currently experimenting with Dataproc and I followed the Google tutorial to spin-up a Hadoop cluster with Jupyter and Spark. Everything works smoothly. I use the following command:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-cluster \
    --project proj-name \
    --bucket notebooks-storage \
    --initialization-actions \
        gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh
```

This command spin-up a cluster with one master and two workers (VM type: n1-standad-4).

I tried adding the following flag:

```
    --num-preemptible-workers 2
```

But it only adds two preemptible workers to the two previous standards VMs. I would like to be able to have all of my workers be preemtible VMs because all of my data is stored on Google Cloud Storage and I don't care about the size of the Hadoop storage.

Is it something sound to do? Is there any way of doings that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not a good idea to have cluster that is exclusively or mostly pVMs. pVMs do not carry any guarantees that they will be available at the time of cluster creation, or even still available in your cluster N hours from now. Preemption, is very bad for jobs (especially ones that run for many hours). Also, even-though your data is in GCS, any shuffle operations will result in data to be written to local disks. Think of pVMs only as supplemental compute power.

For these, and other, reasons we recommend at most 1:1 ratio.

An alternative, since you're working with a notebook, is to use a single node cluster: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/single-node-clusters